# Windows Workflow Foundation 4 and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, workflow-foundation-4

We are evaluating Windows Workflow Foundation 4 to use in MVC 3 based Web Applications. We would like to create flexible order workflows for different projects.
Does anybody know good information about the general architecture or hands-on-labs for this kind of application?
Some concrete questions would be:

- how can you activate a specific controller/action from the workflow?
- what is the best way to communicate between the workflow and the web application (events, wcf services, ...)?

Comment: @Will: why did you close my question? It has been viewed by more than 1000 people and is favorite of a couple. For me the question is still open, because I'm looking for a good way to integrate MVC-Controllers into workflows.

Comment: Sorry, we try to discourage open ended questions like this.  Also, it isn't *exactly* a question; its three.  Its a list-type question asking for links (these types of questions aren't accepted here), a general question (no specific details, might be considered a "low quality" question), and another general question with a subjective slant to it.  If you read the close reason below, you can see that it fits this question(s) well.  If you want further clarification, please ask over on [meta].  Thanks.

Comment: @slfan: I agree! This is a very constructive ask! Just because it doesn't involve syntax doesn't mean it should be closed as not constructive.

Comment: @slfan: Just curious as to what you did integrate mvc3-wwf or if you chose a hybrid, other workflow/bpm, etc,?

Comment: we used our own implementation without using WF. At that time we didn't have enough knowledge and we didn't need all the features WF provides. I would still like to know more about WF.

Comment: shouldn't be closed - it's not open ended as it has concrete questions.

Comment: This question should be opened!

Comment: Absolutely hate the micromanagement of some of these posts- this is very much a useful question, don't get what purpose closing this served.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a nice article on how to start working with WF4 in your ASP.NET MVC app.

[Integrating a persisted WF4.0 workflow with mvc](http://stevenwilliamalexander.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/integrating-a-persisted-wf40-workflow-with-mv/)

Comment: Bad link :( wish it wasn't dead

Answer (score 4):

Another example with video is at below link. (Note: The code attached in the link might not be executable, but it will give some concepts when you study the code and watch the video)

https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Workflow-TV/endpointtv-WF4-in-the-Real-World-Microsoft-Support-ASPNET-MVC-Wizard-Framework

This link is showing how we can preserve the data between requests using tempdata. Since it is a large explanation, I am not repeating the same again here.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the videos for this seem to be down but the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-19-processing-orders-with-windows-workflow) seem to try to show you a way!

Sourced from an [old post/response from 2009](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2bd86d71-6804-4a77-9535-9e28dbc3e5db/windows-workflow-and-mvc?referrer=https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2bd86d71-6804-4a77-9535-9e28dbc3e5db/windows-workflow-and-mvc?forum=aspmvc). An alternative is found on [CodeProject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/42072/flexible-web-ui-workflow-application-through-asp-n), which is also quoted on [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/425209/how-to-implement-workflow-for-existing-asp-net-app) with a longer list of resources.